# Spring Data Solr repositories using JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, maven, solr

I'm trying to create a SpringBoot application which uses solr repositories. I'm following this tutorial:

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.repositories

which says to configure my application with the following class (Example 43):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories
class ApplicationConfig {

  @Bean
  public SolrClient solrClient() {
    EmbeddedSolrServerFactory factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactory("classpath:com/acme/solr");
    return factory.getSolrServer(); // getSolrServer does not exist
  }

  @Bean
  public SolrOperations solrTemplate() {
    return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
  }
}
```

The problem is if I do that it doesn't recognise `getSolrServer()` as a method of `factory`. Indeed, if you look at the [most recent API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.html) for `EmbeddedSolrServerFactory` you don't find that method, but it apparently existed in a [previous version](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-solr/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.html) of the same class.

Maybe it was renamed from `getSolrServer` to `getSolrClient`, for some reason, from one version to another.

Here's my dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Anyway, I tried to change `getSolrServer` to `getSolrClient`, but the return type, i.e. `SolrClient`, is now incompatible. If I try to return `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer`, it gives me an error because it doesn't find `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded`...

Another problem using this would be that `SolrTemplate` doesn't require a `EmbeddedSolrServer`, so this is not a good option...

Comment: What is version for "spring-boot-starter-data-solr" in your pom.

Comment: @ShivaKumarSS No version specified, so I guess it takes the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I am using eclipse not spring suite, Assuming spring suite using latest version of `spring-boot-starter-data-solr ( 1.4.2 )` and you need to add an entry for `solr-core 5.x` in your pom.

Since `EmbeddedSolrServer` is extending `SolrClient`, follows Java `IS-A` relationship and it should be compatible with SolrClient. This binary is part of solr-core.

Your code need to use `getSolrClient` itself and it should be compatible with `SolrClient`

> Dependencies in pom.xml is as follows

[image]

> Here we go with our code base without any errors.

[image]

Comment: Just edited my answer with pom.xml entries. can you try with it.

Comment: Now, by using the versions you're suggesting, I've the method `getSolrServer`, but it gives me an error because `SolrTemplate` doesn't require a `SolrClient`.

Comment: I just edited my answer with code snippet. pls check.

Comment: With your configurations, I don't have the method `getSolrClient` but only `getSolrServer`.

Comment: If you have spring-data-solr in dependency then pls remove it.make sure you have only those dependencies which are mentioned in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128866/discussion-between-shiva-kumar-ss-and-nbro).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating SolrClient bean, create EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean object and pass that object to solr template to create SolrTemplate object. Here is my config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.ida.*.repository")
@Profile("dev")
public class SolrConfigDev {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean solrServerFactoryBean() {
        EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean();

        factory.setSolrHome(environment.getRequiredProperty("solr.solr.home"));

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }
}
```

In addition, you have to add solr-core to you pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

More information about this topic, you can find [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-configuration/) in this blog by Petri Kainulainen.